# How to describe "the digits of n" mathematically where n is an integer?

Tags: proof-writing

Suppose n = 12345

The sum of the digits of n = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 15

For example, in Python, we might isolate the digit 1 by writing n[0].

How would one represent the digits of n mathematically?

Comment: Perhaps write $n=\sum \limits_{k=0}^m\left(a_m10^m\right)$, for some natural number $m$ and integers $a_1, \ldots, a_m$.

Comment: Please do not edit questions to have a new meaning after you have already gotten answers. At least not without specifically stating the edits to the question in the question.

Comment: I removed the example that was misleading. The questions i.e. the statements with a question mark at the end of them, are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

> Since any integer n = a<sub>0</sub> + (a<sub>1</sub>)(10) + (a<sub>2</sub>)(10<sup>2</sup>) + ... + (a<sub>x</sub>)(10<sup>x</sup>)
>
> Then the sum of digits = a<sub>0</sub> + a<sub>1</sub> + a<sub>2</sub> + ...

Answer (score 5):

This is wrong.  $6$ divides the sum of the digits of $15$, but $6$ does not divide $15$. $6$ divides $12$, but $6$ does not divide the sum of the digits of $12$.

What is true is that $3$ divides $n$ if and only if $3$ divides the sum of the digits of $n$.  $6$ divides $n$ if and only if $3$ divides the sum of the digits of $n$ and the last digit of $n$ is even.

... or maybe you're working in base $7$?

Comment: Similarly, $ 6 | 36$, but $6 \nmid (3 + 6)$

Comment: The truthfulness of the statement was not the point. I did not expect the statement to be true. The point of this question was to find out how to represent "the digits of n" mathematically

Comment: Then why don't you ask the question you really wanted to ask, rather than wasting our time with a different question?

Comment: Please read the title of the post and any sentence with a question mark punctuating it.

Comment: I edited the question to be more clear. You can delete your post now if you like.